# MYSQL How do I Select all emails from a table but limit number of emails with the same domain

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

As the topic sugests I want to select all emails in the list. But limit the number of emails with the same domain.

Lets say i have 500 gmail adressses.

And 2 example.com adresses.

.. and so on..

> I want to just grab 2 of each adress with the same domain.

With this string i can select the number of domains that accurs on each domain so maybe I can do something with this string.

```
SELECT substring_index(email, '@', -1), COUNT(*) FROM emaillist GROUP
BY substring_index(email, '@', -1);
```

Please help!

Comment: do you have auto_increment column in your table?

Comment: @JW.: Does that make a difference?

Comment: @FabianLauer i'll be using that, please wait.

Comment: @FabianLauer see below, the reason why I ask for AUTO_INCREMENTed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MIN(email) AS address1
  IF(MAX(email)==MIN(email),NULL,MAX(email)) AS address2
FROM emaillist
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1);
```

and if you want them in one column

```
SELECT MIN(email) AS address1
FROM emaillist
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1)
UNION
SELECT MAX(email) AS address1
FROM emaillist
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, Email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(EMAIL, '@', -1) Domain
FROM   emaillist a
WHERE  
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    emaillist e
    WHERE   SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.EMAIL, '@', -1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.EMAIL, '@', -1) AND
            a.ID <= e.ID
) <= 2;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ab3d/4)

The above query doesn't use `INDEX`. The effect of that is it will perform `FULL TABLE SCAN` causing the query to be slow if you have a very large database.

My advise for you is to create an extra column and you will have to define an `INDEX` for it, eg,

```
CREATE TABLE emaillist 
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DOMAIN VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    KEY (DOMAIN)
)
```